# PHP File_PDF Examples / Tutorials?

Tags: php, pdf, pear

I've looked through several Google searches now, and continue to keep coming up empty when it comes to finding some end-user documentation for the File_PDF package.

A lot of people have pointed to FPDF, which is a predecessor, and as far I know, no longer compatible.  FPDF hasn't been updated (http://fpdf.org/) since 2008, either.

I've found a few small snippets of code for File_PDF here and there, but nothing over like 20 lines of code.

Then I came across this little "nugget" of wealth: http://dev.horde.org/pdf/

There's plenty of examples, none of which I've looked through yet, but I'm hoping it does the trick.

In the mean time, does anyone else have some recommendations for PDF generation with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using tcpdf, as many examples were provided from their site.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I needed to generate PDF files with PHP that is what I used (admittedly back in '07) with no major problems. 
Things change though and if File_PDF is more intuitive to use or has a better feature-set then you should obviously use it instead.
I feel obliged to point out that there appears to be a later version of File_PDF available at http://pear.php.net/package/File_PDF than at http://dev.horde.org/pdf/
Have you evaluated any of the PDF related classes at http://www.phpclasses.org?

Comment: I've installed the Pear version of File_PDF, but the files on horde.org were the only usage examples for File_PDF that I had come across.

I had no yet looked at phpclasses.org, I suppose I'll dig around there today.